# Numpy array inverse and join

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this bumpy 2d array and want to reverse it and add it after each item to the original file:

```
arr =
[[1,2],
[3,4],
[5,6]]

arr2 =
[[1,2],
[2,1],
[3,4],
[4,3],
[5,6],
[6,5]]
```

Comment: is this a numpy array or a python list?

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you

```py
arr =[[1,2],
[3,4],
[5,6]]

new_arr = []
for a in arr:
    new_arr.append(a)
    new_arr.append(list(reversed(a)))
print(new_arr)
```

This is more advance way

```py
arr =[[1,2],
[3,4],
[5,6]]

new_arr = [x for a in arr for x in [a, a[::-1]]]

print(new_arr)
```

This code works for both `python list` or `numpy array`

There is only a minor change in code.

```py
import numpy as np
arr =np.array([[1,2],
[3,4],
[5,6]])

new_arr = [x for a in arr for x in [a, a[::-1]]]

new_arr = np.array(new_arr) # edited
```

Comment: why do you use list.append in a list comprehension? Wouldn't `[x for a in arr for x in [a, a[::-1]]]` be simpler without the side effects?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a numpy array, you could [stack them depth-wise](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) and reshape it:

```
out = np.dstack([arr, arr[:, [1,0]]]).reshape(-1,2)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 3],
       [5, 6],
       [6, 5]])
```

Comment: A minor variation on this:`np.hstack((arr,arr[:,::-1])).reshape(-1,2)`

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, looks like `np.c_` or `np.column_stack` also do the job too.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`fliplr`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html), [`vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) and [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

```
arr2 = (np.hstack([arr,np.fliplr(arr)])
          .reshape(-1,arr.shape[1])
        )
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 3],
       [5, 6],
       [6, 5]])
```